# Wordpress different featured image size for different post types

Tags: php, wordpress, post, thumbnails

You can enable featured images for posts and set their size by using the following code in your function.php file:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(107, 69, true);
```

but this sets the image size globally for any post types. Im using wordpress 3.0 and have created my own custom post type. Is it possible to apply a different featured thumbnail sizes for different post types?

Thanks

Scott

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your theme functions file, you can define new image sizes that apply to any images uploaded from then forward:

[`add_image_size('new-thumbnail-size',600,340, true)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Once you've defined a new image size, you can use [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) as usual but include the new image size to display that instead of the thumbnail default:

`the_post_thumbnail( 'new-thumbnail-size' )`

A little bit more detail: http://gavinsmith.me/2010/10/multiple-post-thumbnail-featured-image-sizes-in-wordpress/

Comment: I know all this already, but thats not what I asked. if I set a featured image its going to use the size post-thumbnails but what I want to happen is that if Im in a different post type when i use featured image it uses a different size other than post thumbnails.

Comment: That's what I was getting at - if you register your own image sizes, you can edit the instance of your featured image accordingly. You can run an `if elseif else` or a `switch` using `$post->post_type` in your loop - if it's post type A, print `the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-type-A' )`, if it's post type B, print `the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-type-B' )`. That any better?

Answer (score 10):

To answer your question, currently (Version 3.4.1) it is not possible. And the reason is simple: If you upload a file to your media library your image is not related to any post nor even a post_type, so wordpress cannot know, that this file has to be resized into a different format.

Realizing your wish (as it is one of mine too) means, that the image has to be created, if an image is added to a post with a custom post type.
So until this might be realized (I do not expect that this will come in time) you have to define your custom image size globally dealing the disadvantage, that every file you are uploading will be stored multiple times (one per `add_image_size()` call), even if you will use only one image in your template.

Comment: Even if I agree with Gavin's response about switching the post thumbnail based on post type as a workaround, I agree this is the correct answer.

As RRikesh says, the image is not related to a post at the time it is being uploaded to the media gallery, and all thumbnails are being generated. Even if we can use multiple image thumbnail sizes and then switch based on post type, that won't prevent the file to be saved for each image size defined globally. For large websites, having multiple post types, that can easily consume lot of space on disk senseless.